# Mobile terminal build app doesnt show on iOS7 springboard

Tags: mobile, ios7, terminal, theos

I am coding iOS APP on iPad using mobile terminal and THEOS.
I am following this tutorial https://sites.google.com/site/theostutorials/chapter-2-my-first-app/lesson-3-build-and-test

I followed all the steps successfully but my app doesnt show on springBoard.
I run command "make package install" on mobile terminal, it creates .deb file. I installed that deb file using iFile then reboot device, respring too but app doesnt show on SpringBoard

Device = iPad 3,3 
iOS 7.0.4

Comment: You should be using a mac/hackintosh + Xcode to do this.

Comment: Ya i have Xcode on mavericks, but I was using on-device tools, to write and compile code on device using theos coz I dont have apple developer program membership

Comment: You don't need the apple developer program to do jailbreak development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally now it appears. You have to reboot device twice. Only one time resping or reboot doesnt work